# Gmail - problem with Hangouts and filters

Tags: gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I've set up filter in Gmail to label all mails/chats/Hangouts with my wife. Filter is quite simple:

- `from:her-email-address@gmail.com`
- set label "Wife"
- never send to spam

But now every chat/Hangouts message goes to the main Inbox, not only to the “Chat” folder (it is not archived—I don't want this). When I apply the “skip the inbox” command, both chats and emails go directly to “Wife” directory and then my Android phone doesn't inform me about new mail.

This is quite annoying. Is there a way to solve this situation and split mail and chat filters?

Comment: Are you suggesting that your hangout messages _used to be_ archived automatically? I don't recall that I have ever been able to archive these hangout messages - but I would like to very much! http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/how-do-you-auto-archive-chat-hangout-messages-in-gmail

Comment: I'm not suggesting that they _used to be_, I'm saying they _are_ archived automatically (both from my wife and other users) when filters are not active.
Maybe my situation is different because I use Google account with my own domain? New features (and bugs ;) ) are implemented later then in 'open' accounts.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. My question would seem to be very similar, except I'm on plain old Gmail and do not currently have any filters affecting this "hangout" user, yet still my hangout messages do not appear to get archived without me manually doing so!?

Comment: Can you set up filter on `label:chats` or `is:chats` criteria and test it with archive command? Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: I made some tests. First I had created new Gmail accound (@gmail.com, not own domain) and then used to 'talk' with me (two separated computers in one network). On both accounts Hangout messages go directly to 'chat' folder, they are archived automatically without filters.

Comment: Yes! It does auto-archive afterall; providing you don't have _any_ filters set on that user. Thanks for that. I had previously deleted a filter on this user (very similar to yours as it happens), but it appears to have taken a bit of time for it to take effect. (AFAIK you can't (reliably) set filters on labels - so says the warning dialog if you try to do so.) Sorry, this doesn't really help you unfortunately - it just confirms your problem - if you have a filter on a user then hangouts from that user aren't archived!? Weird.

Comment: You can set the Gmail app on your Android to (separately) alert you to new messages in specific labels. [How to get notified of new automatically archived emails in Gmail?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found this Q&A. When I went to run some tests, I discovered that Gmail had added a checkbox for just this issue called "Don't include chats" (see screenshot of Search Options drop-down menu). I've been using this for almost a week and it seems to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can match Chat or Hangout history messages with `is:chat`.

The opposite works too:

```
from:person -is:chat
```

Thus, you need:

- `from:her-email-address@gmail.com -is:chat`
- set label "Wife"
- never send to spam

Comment: Warning message seen when you create filter based on labels:
`Filter searches containing "label:",  "in:", "is:", or stars criteria (i.e. "has:yellow-star") are not recommended as they will never match incoming mail.`
This filter doesn't work. We (I and @w3d) have tested this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but if you want these chats to be archived and not showing in your inbox, you should use "Skip inbox (archive it)" option when creating a filter.

So your filter should be something like this:

```
from:her-email-address@gmail.com
Skip the Inbox (Archive it)
Apply the label: Wife
Never send it to Spam
```